# jquery nested .each

Tags: jquery, loops, for-loop, foreach, each

```
$(".globalTabs").each(function(){
    var $globalTabs = $(this);
    var parent = $globalTabs.parent('form');

    //initiate jQuery UI tabs
    $globalTabs.tabs();

    var ATBwidth = $globalTabs.parent().outerWidth();
    var tabsWidth = 0;

    //get total width of all li/tabs
    $(".globalTabs .ui-tabs-nav li").each(function() {
     tabsWidth += $(this).outerWidth();
    });


    if(tabsWidth >= ATBwidth){
       //doing something here
    }


});
```

which is breaking due to the nested `.each` - is there a simple way around this issue?

breaking = functionality after the second loop, which refers to `$globalTabs` is no longer triggering, because it is undefined.

**Stupid mistake:**

After the second loop, in this section I was referring to the selector twice.

So, with `$(".globalTabs").each(function(){` this of course won't work:
`$globalTabs.find(".globalTabs .ui-tabs-nav li").hide();`

Had nothing to do with the loops.

Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: What do you mean, "is breaking"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using the value of `this` pass in the value from `.each(index, value)`

```
$(".globalTabs").each(function(index, value){
    var $globalTabs = $(value);
    var parent = $globalTabs.parent('form');

    //initiate jQuery UI tabs
    $globalTabs.tabs();

    var ATBwidth = $globalTabs.parent().outerWidth();
    var tabsWidth = 0;

    //get total width of all li/tabs
    $(".globalTabs .ui-tabs-nav li").each(function(index, secondValue) {
     tabsWidth += $(secondValue).outerWidth();
    });


    if(tabsWidth >= ATBwidth){
       //doing something here
    }


});
```

Comment: Doesn't help clarify anything if you give each pair of callback arguments the same name. :-)

Comment: needs `tabsWidth += $(secondValue).outerWidth();

Comment: @Jason change to: $(secondValue)

Comment: still breaks after the second loop

Comment: @Jason can you please edit your question to define what "breaks" means, it is not clear.

Comment: the functionality that refers to `$globalTabs` after the second loop is not firing - `$globalTabs` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your multiple `this` variables are getting confused? Try using arguments in the callback function instead (http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$(".globalTabs").each(function(i,tab){
    var $globalTabs = $(tab);

// ...

$(".globalTabs .ui-tabs-nav li").each(function(j,myli) {
    tabsWidth += $(myli).outerWidth();
});
```